# JSON Array and Object into Table View with Java

Tags: java, android, json

JSON looks like:

```
   [{"pmid":"2","name":"MANAGEMENT","result":"1","properties":[{"prop_id":"32","prop_name":" Tower","address":"281 Lakeshore","city":"Euclid","state":"OH","zip":"44142","lat":"54.5","long":"-81.5034"}]},{"pmid":"1","name":"ONE","result":"18","properties":[{"prop_id":"3","prop_name":"Chase","address":"146 Goon Blvd.","city":"City","state":"OH","zip":"12345","lat":"46.35","long":"-83.1138"},{"prop_id":"6","prop_name":"Club Apartments","address":"4600 Barrington Club","city":"Columbus","state":"OH","zip":"43520","lat":"40.436","long":"-83.048"}]}]
```

Using Android Studio, trying to retrieve with:

```
private static String url = "http://appurl.com/apis/pagement_list.php";
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "properties";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "prop_id";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "prop_id";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "prop_id";
```

After naming the nodes, I am retrieving the JSON with the following:

```
   @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();



        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);


        if (jsonStr != null) {
            // We create out JSONObject from the data
            JSONObject jObj = null;
            try {
                JSONArray mJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                JSONObject mJsonObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                String pmid = mJsonObject.getString("pmid");
                String name = mJsonObject.getString("name");
                String result = mJsonObject.getString("result");


                JSONArray mJsonArrayProperty = mJsonObject.getJSONArray("properties");
                for (int i = 0; i < mJsonArrayProperty.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject mJsonObjectProperty = mJsonArrayProperty.getJSONObject(i);

                    String prop_id = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("prop_id");
                    String prop_name = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("prop_name");
                    String address = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("address");
                    String city = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("city");
                    String state = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("state");
                    String zip = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("zip");
                    String lat = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("lat");
                    String lon = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("long");

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, prop_name);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_PHONE, address);




                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
            else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_PHONE}, new int[] { R.id.name,
                R.id.email, R.id.mobile});

        setListAdapter(adapter);


    }

}
```

I am able to successfully retrieve into the TableView the first Array, Tower, with Lakeshore Address. But, I do not know how to get to the other pieces of JSON, the other name, for instance.

It would be great if the name could be displayed right before the array including prop_name. And the name only needs to be displayed once, in the case there are multiple prop_name under it.

Comment: store `name` in `contact` HashMap

Comment: You should you a library like Gson to do such work. For example doing your way if 1 attribute is not present, you throw an exception...

Comment: Storing name in contact does display name, thanks. But I need to display all the names, it is only showing one currently, the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether I understand your question correctly, but to me the code looks like it is only extracting the sub-array of the first element of the outer array in the second line after the start of the **try {** block:

```
JSONObject mJsonObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

you should probably do something like:

```
try {
  JSONArray mJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
  int length = mJsonArray.length();
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    JSONObject mJsonObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    ...
    String name = mJsonObject.getString("name");
    JSONArray mJsonArrayProperty = mJsonObject.getJSONArray("properties");
    int innerLength = mJsonArrayProperty.length();
    for (int k = 0; k < innerLength; k++) {
      JSONObject mJsonObjectProperty = mJsonArrayProperty.getJSONObject(k);
      String prop_name = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("prop_name");
      String address = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("address");
      ...
      // hashmap for single contact
      HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
      // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
      contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, prop_name);
      contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
      contact.put(TAG_PHONE, address);
      // adding contact to contact list
      contactList.add(contact);
    }
  }
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
...
```

note that the counter **k** for the inner for loop is different from the one of the outer loop **i**. The hashmap is not temporary, it is passed to the add method of the collection and hence survives.

Comment: what goes in  for (...) {

Comment: that is really great. How do I only show the respective name once, even if it repeats. I just want to show the name once, and then its subarrays under it.

Comment: just set name to "" after using it for the first time, e.g. after adding the contact to the contact list.